# Error with LARAVEL SAIL [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed]

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-sail

I'm having a problem with `laravel sail`, it happens that I just cloned the repository and it is unchanged, the `docker-compose.yml` is totally intact, however, after executing `./vendor/bin/sail up` I have the containers up and when I try doing the migrations throws me the following error

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Docker-compose.yml

```
    # For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            # - pgsql
            - redis
            # - selenium
    # selenium:
    #     image: 'selenium/standalone-chrome'
    #     volumes:
    #         - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
    #     networks:
    #         - sail
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping"]
#    pgsql:
#        image: postgres:13
#        ports:
#            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-5432}:5432'
#        environment:
#            PGPASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD:-secret}'
#            POSTGRES_DB: '${DB_DATABASE}'
#            POSTGRES_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
#            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD:-secret}'
#        volumes:
#            - 'sailpostgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
#        networks:
#            - sail
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sailredis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
    # memcached:
    #     image: 'memcached:alpine'
    #     ports:
    #         - '11211:11211'
    #     networks:
    #         - sail
    mailhog:
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
#    sailpostgresql:
#        driver: local
    sailredis:
        driver: local
```

.env file

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:DXP6IaYhvLqI2fOLq672Bm2xilfehXgjTyrxj+8dcR8=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://ficha.test

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=ficha_caractetizacion
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=memcached

REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Comment: `DB_HOST=mysql` is that a valid hostname?

Comment: well... this is the container's name, I thing thats valid. I try with another host, but not works

Comment: That DB HOST is correct when using sail. I too am getting this redis issue, but it does not seem to affect my app, just litters the error log. I can still use redis.

Answer (score 15):

Are you sure you are inside the container?
if you are trying to run the command outside the container, you can run
`docker exec -it <container_id> php artisan migrate`
or `sail shell`, then run your command